# Running Docker-Compose Commands With Fabric

Tags: django, fabric, docker-compose

I have a Django site running in Docker containers, which uses docker-compose to manage the various containers (database, nginx, etc.).  There are a few Django tasks that I use for site maintenance using the Django `manage.py` command.  They commands take the form of:
`manage.py updateflickr --settings=mysite.myproj.prod`

Running under docker-compose, they look like:
`docker-compose run --rm app manage.py updateflickr --settings=mysite.myproj.prod`

My problem is that when I try to run these same commands using Fabric, it appears that the settings file I am specifying is not being used.  Django is returning database connection errors, which typically mean that it is not getting the correct database information, or in this case the connection specified in `mysite.myprod.prod`

My Fabric file looks like:

```
import os

from fabric.api import *


env.hosts = ['myserver.com']
env.user = "myuser"
env.key_filename = '~/.ssh/do_rsa'
env.shell = '/bin/bash -c'

@task
def updateflickr():
    run('docker-compose run --rm app python manage.py updateflickr --settings=mysite.myproj.prod')
```

I have also expirimented with setting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable in my `docker-compose.yml` but am getting the same results.  Finally, the last thing I tried was wrapping the command in a shell script.  Same results - if I run on the server, it runs fine.  If I run the shell script from Fabric, I get database connection issues.

**UPDATE**

I am not so sure this is so much a question about Fabric, then a question about how docker-compose runs.  If I try the following:

`ssh -t me@myserver.com 'docker-compose run --rm app python manage.py updateflickr --settings=mysite.myproj.prod'`

I still get the same results.  There must be something different about loading up an interactive shell with just sending a command.  I have tried using `ssh` with and without a `-t` flag, because docker-compose might need a `pty` active.

Comment: Have you tired adding `-T` option to `run` ?

Comment: Good idea.  I did not notice that docker-compose had a way to disable the pseudo-tty as well.  I will give that a shot.

Comment: Nope, `-T` did not change the output.

Comment: Can you start Django's shell and execute: `import sys; sys.argv` to see is everything coming in?